# How can I delete old objects in parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

Is any way to delete old objects when using parse.com database?
For example, if user saves it's position,
is any way to delete the users position after some period of time when he disconnects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this question is old, there is a new-ish feature Parse has implemeneted - Cloud Code. I recommend you take a look at the documentation around Background jobs within Cloud Code. Perhaps you may run a background job that will "clean up" your old data.

Here is the link:

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs

Answer (score 2):

More to what @Phil said, you can run some other code (not in your app), something like stand alone script that deletes whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

For what version? iOS? if you're using the iOS SDK, what you could do is when they log back in, check to see how much time has passed, and then delete their position in whatever PFObject has the users position. Outside of that maybe this could be done with Cloud code.